# Ansible: Handling of Forward Slash Fails in Dict Obj. Lookup

Tags: python, json, dictionary, ansible, yaml

#### Code:

```
- name: Testing PyATS

  tasks:

  - name: Read in parse_genie role
    include_role:
      name: clay584.parse_genie

  - name: show interfaces
    ios_command:
      commands:
        - show interfaces
    register: interfaces

  - name: Set Fact Genie Filter
    set_fact: 
      pyats_interfaces: "{{ interfaces['stdout'][0] | parse_genie(command='show interfaces', os='iosxe') }}"

  - name: Debug
    debug:
      var: pyats_interfaces.GigabitEthernet0/0
```

#### Expect:

```
 "ansible_facts": {
        "pyats_interfaces": {
            "GigabitEthernet0/0": {
                "arp_timeout": "04:00:00",
                "arp_type": "arpa",
                "auto_negotiate": true,
                "bandwidth": 1000000,
                "counters": {
                    "in_broadcast_pkts": 0,
                    "in_crc_errors": 0,
                    "in_errors": 0,
                    "in_frame": 0,
                    "in_giants": 0, etc.
```

#### Getting:

`"pyats_interfaces.GigabitEthernet0/0": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'dict object' has no attribute 'GigabitEthernet0'"`

It appears the / is being treated as an escape character and causing the variable to show up as undefined when searching the dict. for G0/0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 equivalent syntax to address vars inside a dictionaries in ansible:

- The dot notation:

```
some.var.to.address
```

- The bracket notation:

```
some['var']['to']['address']
```

Both notations can be mixed in the way you want e.g. `some['var']['to'].address`

Although they are equivalent, some cases force you to use the bracket notation.

- when the name of the field comes from a variable e.g. `my_var[item]`
- when the name of the field contains special characters e.g. `my_var['field with spaces']`

You are in this latest case. So replacing your debug line with the following should fix your problem:

```
- name: Debug
  debug:
    var: pyats_interfaces['GigabitEthernet0/0']
```